# Does Jellal love Erza?

Tags: fairy-tail

Throughout *Fairy Tail*, we see that Erza loves Jellal and just him. Some examples are her blushing, trying to kiss him, and when she was turned into a little child just before Tartaros she thought her biggest problem was Jellal thinking he likes them more matured.

But does Jellal reciprocate those feelings even though he rejected her?

Comment: When she wants to kiss him he rejects her saying he has another girl. She says he's a terrible lier but I think her love is blinding her. She doesn't even consider that a guy and 2 beautiful women living together for 7 years may result in happy nights for him. Now, in one of the last chapters it was disclosed he is no virgin and that Erza is. Sigh, at least he's no lolicon like Zeref banging Mavis

Comment: How is this information revealed? It doesn't seem like a topic easy to discuss

Comment: Without giving any spoilers I'll just say there is a person that uses a kind of magic that renders the enemy powerless if they had sex.

Comment: I knew Mashima likes fanservice but this is getting ridiculous. This is type of ideas that belong to the hentai/eroge genre

Comment: @echomateria Who doesn't like including some sort of sex reference in their work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to an event that occurred in the Grand Magic Games arc. I'm not sure exactly which episode but there was a scene in which Erza and Jellal were speaking and he told her that he was married.

Later when speaking to Ultear who revealed that he wasn't, he gave the notion that he lied because he believes happiness isn't for the guilty of heart.

In a later cameo, Erza says to herself that he is a "bad" liar. Indicating that she knows he's hiding his feelings.

From that scene, I am able to infer that they do in fact both love each other. However, due to all the evil things he has done, he feels the need to seek atonement. That is the premises that Crime Sorcière was formed upon.

Answer (score -1):

I think they truly love each other because Erza cries for Jellal, otherwise she does not cry for other guys. I think Jellal loves her too.

When Erza was going to kiss him, he rejected this. He loves her all of his heart. If he wanted, he would kiss her but he didn't do that.

Jellal loves Erza, that's 100% sure.

Answer (score -2):

Of course he does. However, during an episode, they **almost** kiss, and he says they are married.

Afterwards, he tells Ultear that people breaking the law cannot be in love with innocent people.

Erza knows from the start that he was lying.

Comment: Got any proof of this? Answers on SE need to say more than just "Of course!"

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Jellal is in love with Erza. However, being who he is, he believes he is unworthy of her. This can be seen in the GMG arc when Erza and himself are about to kiss but don't. He says later that he couldn't do it as he was punishing himself for his past actions.